# ftp_put(): No such file or directory in

Tags: php

The script is:

```
<?php 

$filep = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']; 
$ftp_server = $_POST['server'];
$ftp_user_name = $_POST['user'];
$ftp_user_pass = $_POST['password'];
$paths = $_POST['pathserver'];
$name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user: $ftp_user_name";
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user: $ftp_user_name";
}

$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $name, $filep, FTP_BINARY, "22");

if (!$upload) {
    echo "Error: FTP upload has failed!";
} else {
    echo "Good: Uploaded $name to $ftp_server";
}

ftp_close($conn_id);
set_time_limit(300);

?>
```

When I run this `php` script there is warning:

> Warning: ftp_put(): localfile.txt: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/temp/index.php on line 26

`getcwd();` shows that I'm in the `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/temp` directory and in this directory there is file `localfile.txt`

What is wrong ?

Comment: what are the folder and file's permissions set to?

Comment: you're also using `FTP_BINARY` which shouldn't be used for text files. Use `FTP_ASCII`.

Comment: I am questioning the suggestive edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17404204 and rejected it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the permissions are Read and Write. If I use FTP_ASCII there is another error: "ftp_put(): REST: Resuming transfers not allowed in ASCII mode in"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace:

```
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $name, $filep, FTP_BINARY, "22");
```

to:

```
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $name, $filep, FTP_BINARY);
```

Comment: Its not working for me !! getting same error Warning: ftp_put():